# Failed formating usb-drive, cant read

Tags: usb, usb-drive, format

Tried to format USB drive, a Kingston 32 GB.

Apologies for my noobiness.

I used the file explorer tool.

Selected the options:
override al info with 0s
and use nfts

started it and I believe the window closed, waited a moment no window showing it was still in procces as I could tell.
So I took out the drive and put it back in.
Got an error message saying the formating failed, and I can see the device anymore.
searched for kingston among all files and found:
2 files and 2 folders, all in:

```
dev/dick/by-id
```

Seemed those files were blocking the drive so I used:

```
sudo rm -rf /path/to/directory/*
```

And were deleted, still cant see the drive, pull out and back on, the 2 files reapear and still cant see the drive.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you were still wiping the previous partition table and file system when you took the drive out (unplugged it). That kind of overwriting takes a very long time.

The files in

```
/dev/disk/by-id
```

are special files, created by the system. You should not tamper with them, but I think that they are created again, when you reboot your computer.

-o-

It should work to create a new partition table and file system in your USB drive. I suggest that you install mkusb and use the options at the wipe menu according to the folloing links

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

[mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

This way you can wipe the first megabyte (to be sure to get a good system without any disturbing data), and use any tool to create a new partition table and file system. You can also let mkusb do the whole job and create a partition table plus an NTFS file system, which you want. *The NTFS option in the wipe menu works for all sizes of drives*, also bigger than 2 TB.

[image]